# How to remove records from table in bulk with hibernate hql?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, bulk

I am trying delete records in bulk from database table `Student`.

Everything is running fine but my question is **:**

Is there any limitation when my list (refer to query: studentIdList) size is greater than 1000000 in given piece of code? Do I need to do anything extra in such situation?

```
String hql = "delete from Student where id in (:studentIdList)";
session.createQuery(hql).setParameterList("studentIdList",studentIdList).executeUpdate();
session.flush();
```

Comment: No, I have not dummy data in my database, but it can be possible. But it might be possible that we can run successfully one time and break some time based on some database transaction limit or something else. So just need expert advice on this topic. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are few things to be considered.

1.) how `cache` will behave if configured.

2.) For `1000000 records`, definitely load test needs to be done. Are there any changes of **OOM** error.

You can try with above `HQL` and `Hibernate Batch` and then measure and come up with the statistics. Blindly telling the stats is impossible.

Also instead of using `IN operator`, how about the performance of using `==` in loop.

```
WHERE id = 1;

Is transformed to a simple equality filter.

WHERE id IN (1);

Is transformed into an array match of:

WHERE id = ANY(ARRAY[1]);
```

I will suggest you to please try, it will be an interesting exercise for you.

After reading more and experimenting, Batch will internally make a final query with `IN` operator only.SO using batch will add extra process in between, my thought using `HQL with IN` for delete operation will be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time :) what do you mean by `Also instead of using IN operator, how about the performance of using == in loop.`? I didn't get it :(

Comment: @VishalZanzrukia something like iterating over list of id's and forming HQL for every iteration and executing, instead of just passing complete arrayList to HQL.

Comment: It will take much time, I read this method everywhere on internet for bulk processing for delete functionality in hql.

Comment: @VishalZanzrukia few more details added in the answer